# Creating An HtmlTable Using An ASP.NET Repeater Dynamically Bound to an Object List

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm creating a table inside a repeater programmatically. My problem is that the cells in the item template part don't render properly. They are showing up as text nodes after the table's markup. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the table cells rendering properly?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var dogs = new List<Dog>
                {
                    new Dog { Name = "Rex", Breed = "Russell Terrier" },
                    new Dog { Name = "Fido", Breed = "Poodle" },
                    new Dog { Name = "Fetcher", Breed = "Golden Retriever" },
                };

                var repeater = new Repeater { ID = "Repeater1" };
                repeater.DataSource = dogs;
                repeater.DataBind();

                AddHeader(repeater);
                AddItems(repeater, dogs);

                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(repeater);
            }
        }

        private void AddHeader(Repeater repeater)
        {
            var repeaterItem = new RepeaterItem(0, ListItemType.Header);
            var table = new HtmlTable();
            var row = new HtmlTableRow();
            var cell1 = new HtmlTableCell("th") { InnerText = "Name" };
            var cell2 = new HtmlTableCell("th") { InnerText = "Breed" };
            row.Cells.Add(cell1);
            row.Cells.Add(cell2);
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            repeaterItem.Controls.Add(table);
            repeater.Controls.Add(repeaterItem);
        }

        private void AddItems(Repeater repeater, List<Dog> dogs)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < repeater.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var repeaterItem = new RepeaterItem(i + 1, ListItemType.Item);
                var row = new HtmlTableRow();
                var cell1 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = dogs[i].Name };
                var cell2 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = dogs[i].Breed };
                row.Cells.Add(cell1);
                row.Cells.Add(cell2);
                repeaterItem.Controls.Add(row);
                repeater.Controls.Add(repeaterItem);
            }
        }

        private sealed class Dog
        {
            public string Breed { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Thanks to Rob's help, I was able to get the code working. Now I have a fully-functional Repeater being loaded entirely in the code-behind with data-binding. Nice!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ExtensionMethods.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dogs = new List<Dog>
            {
                new Dog { Name = "Rex", Breed = "Russell Terrier" },
                new Dog { Name = "Fido", Breed = "Poodle" },
                new Dog { Name = "Fetcher", Breed = "Golden Retriever" },
            };

            var repeater = new Repeater
            {
                ID             = "Repeater1",
                HeaderTemplate = new CustomTemplate(ListItemType.Header),
                ItemTemplate   = new CustomTemplate(ListItemType.Item),
                FooterTemplate = new CustomTemplate(ListItemType.Footer),
                DataSource     = dogs
            };

            repeater.DataBind();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(repeater);
        }

        // Custom template class to add controls to the repeater's header, item and footer sections.
        private sealed class CustomTemplate : ITemplate
        {
            private ListItemType ListItemType { get; set; }

            public CustomTemplate(ListItemType type)
            {
                ListItemType = type;
            }

            public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
            {
                if (ListItemType == ListItemType.Header)
                {
                    var table = new LiteralControl();
                    var head = new HtmlGenericControl("thead");
                    var row = new HtmlTableRow();
                    row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell("th") { InnerText = "Breed" });
                    row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell("th") { InnerText = "Name" });
                    head.Controls.Add(row);
                    table.Text = string.Format("<table>{0}<tbody>", head.RenderHtml());
                    container.Controls.Add(table);
                }
                else if (ListItemType == ListItemType.Item)
                {
                    var row = new HtmlTableRow();

                    var cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
                    cell1.Controls.Add(new Literal { ID = "LiteralBreed" });
                    row.Cells.Add(cell1);

                    var cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();
                    cell2.Controls.Add(new Literal { ID = "LiteralName" });
                    row.Cells.Add(cell2);

                    container.Controls.Add(row);
                    container.DataBinding += new EventHandler(Container_DataBinding);
                }
                else if (ListItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
                {
                    var footer = new LiteralControl("</tbody></table>");
                    container.Controls.Add(footer);
                }
            }

            // Event handler to populate the dog's breed and name in the table when data-binding occurs.
            private void Container_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var item = sender as RepeaterItem;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    var dog = ((Dog)item.DataItem);

                    var breed = item.FindDescendantsByType<Literal>().Single(x => x.ID == "LiteralBreed");
                    breed.Text = dog.Breed;

                    var name = item.FindDescendantsByType<Literal>().Single(x => x.ID == "LiteralName");
                    name.Text = dog.Name;
                }
            }
        }

        private sealed class Dog
        {
            public string Breed { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in your logic you are creating a table with a header in the AddHeader method and adding it to the repeater, that will create:

```
<table>
<tbody><tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Breed</th>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Then you add the list items to the repeater, yes to the repeater, not to the first table.
You are adding table rows to the repeader after the table, and the browser will render this rows and cells as just text nodes because they don't have their parent tbody table elements.

The repeater writes HTML so you need to find a way to have the open and close table tags

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <asp:Repeater ID="fooRepeater" runat="server" ></asp:Repeater>
    </tbody>       
</table>
```

So the repeater render will be something like:
    
        RexRussell Terrier 
    
For each item

I believe your logic is wrong if you want each item in the repeater as a table you need to change your code like this:

```
    private void AddItems(Repeater repeater, List<Dog> dogs)
    {
        var repeaterItem = new RepeaterItem(0, ListItemType.Header);
        var table = new HtmlTable();
        var row = new HtmlTableRow();
        var cell1 = new HtmlTableCell("th") { InnerText = "Name" };
        var cell2 = new HtmlTableCell("th") { InnerText = "Breed" };
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        row.Cells.Add(cell2);
        table.Rows.Add(row);

        for (var i = 0; i < repeater.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            repeaterItem = new RepeaterItem(i + 1, ListItemType.Item);
            row = new HtmlTableRow();
            cell1 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = dogs[i].Name };
            cell2 = new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = dogs[i].Breed };
            row.Cells.Add(cell1);
            row.Cells.Add(cell2);

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        repeaterItem.Controls.Add(table);
        repeater.Controls.Add(repeaterItem);

    }
```

Everything will happen in the AddItems method and you no longer need the AddHeader.
If you want each repeater item be the row of a table the logic must be different.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my code if you want to check out the final solution.