# Creating An HtmlTable Using An ASP.NET Repeater Dynamically Bound to an Object List using ExtensionMethods.WebControls;

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to create a repeater control and create the template programattically in webform. I found the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110594/creating-an-htmltable-using-an-asp-net-repeater-dynamically-bound-to-an-object-l) [Creating An HtmlTable Using An ASP.NET Repeater Dynamically Bound to an Object List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110594/creating-an-htmltable-using-an-asp-net-repeater-dynamically-bound-to-an-object-l)

but it has a using statement for ExtensionMethods.WebControls. That seems to have a method for GenericHtmlControl called RenderHtml.

How do i get ExtensionMethods.WebControls in my project?

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely some code that the author of that question created themselves. To do this yourself as an extension method, you could go:

```
public static string RenderControl(this Control control) 
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    using(StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
    {
        using(Html32TextWriter htmlWriter = new Html32TextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            control.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2007/11/05/dynamically-render-a-web-user-control.aspx